# View-based NSOutlineView cellviews overlapping

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsoutlineview

Is there any way to overlap cellviews in `NSOutlineView`?

`NSView` have no clipsToBounds property. I tried switch on the `wantsLayer` property of the cell view and its superview - rowView, then set outlineView property `setIntercellSpacing:NSMakeSize(0.f, -10.f)`, but views are trimmed to its bounds.
I tried to overload a `NSView`'s visibleRect method and no result. How can I overlap cell views?